# HTML panel to appear/disappear depending on DataTables Select

Tags: javascript, html

Im using datatables responsive/select right now to display some data. How would I go about making it so when I click on any of these rows in the table, it opens up the "col-md-6" panel? So hidden when no rows are selected, then shown when a row is selected.

```
<!-- begin row -->
<div class="row">
    <!-- begin col-2 -->
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="menu-panel"></div>
        <!-- begin panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-inverse">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-heading-btn">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                </div>
                <h4 class="panel-title">Digital Inputs</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-info fade in">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                Click on a Digital Input to edit its properties.
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Input</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>8</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 8</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>9</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 9</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 10</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>11</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 11</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>12</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 12</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>13</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 13</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="gradeA">
                            <td>14</td>
                            <td>Digital Input 14</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end panel -->
    </div>






    <!-- begin col-2 -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- begin panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="form-stuff-2">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-heading-btn">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                </div>
                <h4 class="panel-title">New RTU FZB-1000 - FZB-1000</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="/" method="POST">
                <legend>Digital Input Basic Settings</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Digital Input:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1" disabled />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Display Input:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" checked><br>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Signal Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="device" class="form-control" value="Digital Input 1" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end panel -->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-r-5">Save</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end col-10 -->

</div>
<!-- end row -->
```

```
App.restartGlobalFunction();
App.setPageTitle('Color Admin | Managed Tables - Select');
$.getScript('assets/plugins/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js').done(function() {
$.getScript('assets/plugins/DataTables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js').done(function() {
    $.getScript('assets/plugins/DataTables/extensions/Select/js/dataTables.select.min.js').done(function() {
        $.getScript('assets/plugins/DataTables/extensions/Responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js').done(function() {
            $.getScript('assets/js/table-manage-select.demo.min.js').done(function() {
                TableManageTableSelect.init();
            });
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: where's your javascript?

Comment: Not much, but thats my current javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.. give your input field id for example
digital input: `id="digital-input-number"` and for digital signal `id="digital-input-name"` and here goes the code...

```
 $('.gradeA td').on('click',function(){
                var text=[];
                 text = $(this).parent().find('td');
                    //console.log(text[0].innerText);
                   // console.log(text[1].innerText);
                $("#digital-input-number").val(text[0].innerText);
                $("#digital-input-name").val(text[1].innerText);


            });
```

this code will put the value of your table to form dynamically i.e you click on one row data of that row goes to the form which i suppose you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any JS, you should attempt this yourself. What I can say is that in order to get what you need, you will have to call the inputs and according to which column is selected on the table, place those values equal to what is selected.

So, if you click on  `Digital Input 1`, set the value for `Digital Input` to the row selected but the first column. It will display the value of `1`.

Then you just need to call the value of the selected column to the `signal name` and it will display `Digital Input 1`.

None of your elements have `id tags`.
In order to do this, your rows and columns will need to have `id tags`. Then you can easily grab the `innerHTML` of the id using JS.

I hope this helps.